# Docker Desktop MacOS Ventura running a bunch of containers on install

Tags: docker, macos-ventura

I've only been playing with docker for a month or so for a node project, but on all 5 computers Ive used it on, 'docker ps' only showed *my* running containers.

I just upgraded to MacOS Ventura and had to reinstall Docker Desktop, which also seems to have gotten an upgrade, and now when I run 'docker ps', I see all the containers below rolling up as docker-local when Docker Desktop starts - I don't need these services (yet) - does docker desktop need them to just run?

```
$docker ps                                                                                                                                                                      
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
2fa10f065b7d   mysql:8              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 months ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   docker-local_mysql_1
51335a27f550   amzlocal:latest      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 months ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                  docker-local_app_1
9db2a34d555c   node:notifications   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 months ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp              docker-local_notifications_1
12ca318b21e2   node:webhooks        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 months ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:3002->3002/tcp              docker-local_webhooks_1
fa122a509c79   redis:buster         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 months ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp              docker-local_redis_1
fd8cba2da499   mongo                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 months ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp            docker-local_mongo_1
e1d8e7ba78e2   memcached            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 months ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:11211->11211/tcp            docker-local_memcached_1
```

Answer (score 0):

to show all containers, try with 'docker ps -a' command
Docker use at init to up all available containers, you can stop them using the 'docker stop ' command (you can specify as many container id's as you need in the same command-line, space-separated)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).